# How to run a script during Gnome log out

Tags: gnome

I would like to run a script to rsync my home directory to another machine whenever I log out of Gnome.  There is a way to hook into the Gnome logout process?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The script /etc/gdm/PostSession/Default is run by root whenever someone quits his X session. You might add there something like

```
if [ ${USERNAME} = "myuser" ];then
  su myuser -c /home/myuser/logout.sh
fi
```

before the exit 0.

Then create a file /home/myuser/logout.sh, make it executable and add your rsync call to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the script to the `~/.bash_logout` script file (create it if it doesn't exist, but make sure to mark it as executable).

I'm actually searching for a way to do this only with the Gnome session, since using `~/.bash_logout` will run for a Gnome session logout, but also any other (BASH) session logout as well (SSH console, etc.).