# Run a command in the background but also concatenate other commands to it?

Tags: syntax

How could I concatenate several commands in a single line, but also run them all in the background ? These didn't work:

```
sleep 1m & && echo "goodbye" & && exit &.
sleep 1m & ; echo "goodbye" & ; exit &.
sleep 1m & echo "goodbye" & exit &.
```

I must have all commands to effect **foreground session**. For example, `exit &` should end foreground session.

Note: I use it as an alternative to the `at` utility. The story of why I need this alternative is long, but it can be told from these questions I asked here (and presented chronologically below), to I sadly didn't have a satisfying solution (regarding my specific case):

- [How to timeout by hours in Bash (and keep timing out even if the session was closed)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332313/how-to-timeout-by-hours-in-bash-and-keep-timing-out-even-if-the-session-was-clo)
- [Making “at” or “sleep” utilities to print stdout in timeout, on the highest of Bash sessions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333201/making-at-or-sleep-utilities-to-print-stdout-in-timeout-on-the-highest-of-b)

Here, the answer by dataved seems promising.

Comment: what is you point by doing that ?

Comment: Added a passage on the end on this.

Comment: you can put them in script and do what ever you want after `sleep` command

Comment: I know, but I want this in one row...

Comment: sorry i can't see any point for doing that

Comment: Do you want the shell that executing this to exit after the end of the execution ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
pid=$$; ( sleep 1; echo goodbye; kill $pid ) & echo hello
```

Comment: Can you combine nohup with that ?...

Comment: You are welcome to answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333538/how-could-i-add-nohup-to-this-command

Answer (score 1):

Well, IMO, the best way to do that and to spare the trouble would be to use the screen utility:

```
1. screen -R <name-of-the-screen-session>
2. <the-command(s)> 
3. ctrl + a + d ### To exit the screen session
4. To log back: screen -x <name-of-the-screen-session>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` is a conditional operator. It will execute the command to the right if-and-only-if the command on the left exited successfully. Since you're executing the command to the left in the background, its return code cannot be determined and things break and don't work as expected.

Don't use `&&`. You should either do `command1 & command2 & command3` or `( command1; command2; command3 )&`. The second one will execute all the commands sequentially in a subshell that's running in the background.

Comment: `sleep 1m & ; exit` brings `syntax error near unexpected token ';'`...

Comment: `command1 & command2 & command3` should do... sorry

Comment: `sleep 1m & exit` doesn't wait one minute... It just quits current session, so sadly this also doesn't seem to work...