# How could I add nohup to a bash command set?

Tags: nohup

I have the following command set which I sometimes run on my VPS. Basically it works fine; It runs in the background and does what I need.

```
WB=$$; (
       sleep 2h;
       echo "Removing PMA and exiting";
       phpdismod mcrypt mbstring;
       apt-get purge phpmyadmin -y;
       service apache2 restart;
       sed -i 's/Include \/etc\/phpmyadmin\/apache.conf/ /g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf;
       kill $WB
) &
```

### The only thing I miss:

The only thing I miss in this command set is a `nohup`. It's important for me to use `nohup` in case I've closed the session or had a power outage in my end --- With a `nohup`, I promise the command set will still be scheduled for execution in the VPS, in such cases.

How could I add a `nohup` to this command set?

Comment: It's better to use `at` command for scheduled jobs.

Comment: How would you use this **very same** command set in `at` ? Please share it in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options, all of which preserve your requirement of terminating your foreground session at the end (which you do with `kill $WB`).

1. If possible, use tmux (or screen). It's the most obvious solution for your use case: a disconnection on your end will just cause a detachment of the tmux session, thus the commands you issued will not stop; after that, you could even re-attach to that session if you wanted to check its output (instead of `tail -f nohup.out`). You wouldn't even need the `kill $WB` trick, as every single command is executed in the foreground, so a simple `exit` will suffice. **Summary**: ssh into your VPS -> execute `tmux` -> type the commands you listed (without the `WB=$$; (`, the `) &` at the end and substituting `kill $WB` with a simple `exit`) -> disconnect, detach and re-attach as needed
2. If you can't or don't want to use tmux, put your commands in a file. The problem here is basically that `nohup` can't execute grouped commands (the concept of subshell is exclusive to bash, you can't execute one with nohup), so you could put your code e.g. in the `/opt/myscript.sh` file:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   #You will pass the PID of the foreground shell as its first argument
   WB=$1

   sleep 2h;
   echo "Removing PMA and exiting";
   phpdismod mcrypt mbstring;
   apt-get purge phpmyadmin -y;
   service apache2 restart;
   sed -i 's/Include \/etc\/phpmyadmin\/apache.conf/ /g' /etc/apache2  /apache2.conf;
   kill $WB
   ```

   Then you can execute it with `nohup /opt/myscript.sh $$ &`
3. If you can't or don't want to put them in a file, just execute them like this: `nohup bash -c " ...your commands here... ; kill $$" &`. The `$$` here will still be referring to the outer foreground shell, as it is substituted before it is executed as the bash `-c` argument.
4. As your script starts with a 2 hour sleep, you may want to consider the `at` program. You can execute `at now + 2 hours` and then type the commands you want to execute 2 hours from then (with 1 minute granularity). Once you have typed all the commands you need, you can exit the "at shell" with Ctrl+D and check with `atq` that your command sequence has been scheduled for execution.
5. You can also execute your script as a heredoc. It's basically the same as option 3, but instead of specifying your commands as the `-c` argument, you give them to bash's standard input. Just be aware that if your script expects arguments, you must specify them during the call to bash, like this:

   ```
   nohup bash -s -- firstArgument secondArgument <<'EOF' &
   ....paste your code here.....
   EOF
   ```

Comment: If you prefer to have the output of your commands on the tty itself, tmux is the tool you want to use (and your only choice, as neither "nohup" nor "at" prints the output to your tty). Install tmux on your VPS, then try this: ssh into your VPS --> execute "tmux" --> execute "while true; do echo test; sleep 1; done" (you will see "test" printed out each second) --> press Ctrl+B, then press "d" to detach your session --> execute "exit" to disconnect from your VPS --> ssh into it again --> execute "tmux attach" and you will see that, while you were disconnected, the loop kept working.

Comment: Any way to auto disabling this message about output redirected to /home/user/nohup.out ?

Comment: Yes, if you don't want the "nohup.out" message from showing, you can add "2>/dev/null" at the end of the command from option 3, before the "&". Thus, the complete command would be ---> nohup bash -c " ...your commands here... ; kill $$" 2>/dev/null &

Comment: Also, if you have new questions please create new ones.

Comment: Yes, and I deleted comments that might heavy on newcomers. It's good your replies are there as it helps. It now worked. Thank you for everything. A few days I ate straw with this and you helped me in a dark time.

Comment: I've published a new question about the `nohup-clear` relations. You are most welcome to answer there if you want and have the spare time. Again thanks! http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333644/why-would-the-clear-command-wont-work-with-nohup-sleep

Comment: Dear @Mario Vitale, I've asked here upon the fifth way (executing this in an heredoc): http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333664/how-to-execute-nohup-in-an-heredocument