# How to execute nohup in an heredocument?

Tags: nohup, timeout, here-document

I have this timeout code block:

```
#!/bin/bash

WB=$1
sleep 2h;
commands...
kill $WB
```

To run the script with `nohup` and in the **background**, I can paste it in a file, and execute:

```
nohup /opt/myscript.sh $$ &
```

### What I aim to achieve:

Instead of pasting it in a file and execute, I would like to execute it directly from an heredoc:

```
/dev/fd/10 10<< 'EOF0'
#!/bin/bash

WB=$1
sleep 2h;
commands...
kill $WB
EOF0
```

I use an heredoc because heredocs are the only way to paste whole code-blocks directly into Bash, and then execute - Very efficient in my case.

### My question:

How could I correctly use `nohup` and `&` with the above hereodc?

Note that the above heredoc is a special one, it's an external heredoc (EOF0), allowing 1 or more heredocs inside it (EOF1, EOF2...).

Comment: Why a here-document and not a function?

Comment: Because you can paste heredocuments directly in bash as-as and execute; It's not the case with functions, if I'm not wrong... If I am, please feel free to post an answer with a function.

Comment: It seems that I just didn't understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i understand, you want to copy the whole content of your script, and paste it as a heredoc to execute it. You can do this, but there's a catch: how do you assign a value to the positional parameter $1 that will appear in the heredoc? The trick here is to pass that argument to bash, by putting it after a `--` sign (which separates the arguments you pass to bash itself from the arguments you pass to the script). Bash must of course read the commands from the stdin, so the `-s` flag must be specified.

To see this at work with the code from your example, open a new pseudoterminal and type this (beware: the quote signs near the first `EOF0` are mandatory, they prevent the expansion of `$1` inside the heredoc itself):

```
nohup bash -s -- $$ <<'EOF0' &
#!/bin/bash

WB=$1
sleep 2h;
commands...
kill $WB
EOF0
```

I must tell you however that EOF0 by itself has no special meaning at all. You can use whatever string you want for a heredoc delimiter (e.g. it could have been `'EOF'` or `'HEREDOC_DELIMITER'`): what matters is that there are single-quotes surrounding it, near the `<<` sign; this prevents any expansion inside the heredoc, which enables you both to use script argument (just like you can use `$1` in the code you posted) and to nest other heredocs.

Comment: Is it true that If I decide not to define a variable inside the code (`WB=$1`), and hence not to kill the process using that variable (`kill $WB`), than I could remove the `$$` from after the `--` in the heredoc declaration?

Comment: Mario, I need the heredoc to be an external heredoc, allowing more heredocs inside it. This is what I use for that `/dev/fd/10 10<< 'EOF0'`.

Comment: The command you want to use, `/dev/fd/10 10<< 'EOF0'`, is just a very roundabout way of executing commands in bash, and is functionally equivalent (although **way** more hacky, you basically copy the heredoc inside the buffer in file descriptor 10 of a new process, and execute it) to `bash -s <<'EOF0'`. Both your code and the one in my answer allow you to put heredocs inside heredocs. About the varable, you're right: the `$$` is just passed as the first argument to the heredoc script, so if you don't need to use `$1` inside the heredoc, you don't need the `$$` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code:

```
nohup bash <<EOF &
WB=$1
sleep 2h;
commands...
kill \$WB
EOF
```

Note that `$1` will be expanded when the code is read; to make `$WB` expand when the code is executed the `$` needs to be quoted.

Comment: I need this in regards to the herecdoc I've shown in the code example (`/dev/fd/10 10<< 'EOF0'`)...